# Making multiple strings the same dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I am trying to make dictionary entries which output the same value for different keys, for example:
    d = {
        ('age', 'old', 'how old', 'maturity'): '18',
        ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o'): 'vowel',
        etc...
        }
This of course saved the entire tuple as the key which is not helpful.

I have tried:

```
d = {
    ('age' or 'old' or 'how old' or 'maturity'): '18',
    ('a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o'): 'vowel',
    etc...
    }
```

But this only works with the first element of the tuple. And if we change the 'or' operators to 'and' the first element stops working.

Ideally the code should run as follows:

```
d = {
    'a', 'b', 'c': 4,
    'd', 'e', 'f': 2,
    }

d['a'] == 4, True
d['c'] == 4, True
d['e'] == 2, True
```

Comment: I went ahead and gave a possible solution, but I am still wondering "Why" you want this done this way. What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to build a simple GUI which takes a simple personal question as input and outputs an answer (i.e. how old are you? how tall are you? etc...), I want to be able to include multiple phrasings of a single question without having to make a difference dict entry for each. This is just me trying to learn python through useless projects.

Comment: Two questions then: What is wrong with just having the one question instead of variations of it? The data structure for this kind of problem would involve a lookup file and/or a table of sorts. You have questions with headers `id` and `questionID` such that another table/file has `id` for each question. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through a list of the keys that you want at that value:

```
d = {}
s = ('a' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o')
for v in s:
   d[v] = 4
assert d == {'a': 4, 'e': 4, 'i': 4, 'o': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {}
for key in ['a', 'c', 'd']:
    myDict[key] = 10
for key in ['b', 'e']:
    myDict[key] = 20
```

You have to assign a value to a key.

Otherwise you can try tuple or list.

Try this and comment, i will suggest different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and `dict.from_keys` to create a list of dicts and then chain them together using `collections.ChainMap` and convert it to dict

```
from collections import ChainMap
keys = [['age', 'old', 'how old', 'maturity'], list('aeio')]
vals = ['18', 'vowel']

dct_gen = (dict.fromkeys(*pair) for pair in zip(keys, vals))
d = dict(ChainMap(*dct_gen))
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 'vowel', 'e': 'vowel', 'i': 'vowel', 'o': 'vowel', 'age': '18', 'old': '18', 'how old': '18', 'maturity': '18'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 approaches can be used to achieve this:

## Approach 1

```
d = {}
for key in ['age', 'old', 'how old','maturity']: 
    d[key] = '18'
for key in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o']: 
    d[key] = 'vowel'
```

## Approach 2

```
d_age_keys_value = '18'
d_vowel_keys_value = 'vowel'
d = {'age': d_age_keys_value, 'old': d_age_keys_value, 'how old': d_age_keys_value, 'maturity': d_age_keys_value, 
     'a': d_vowel_keys_value, 'e': d_vowel_keys_value, 'i': d_vowel_keys_value, 'o': d_vowel_keys_value}
```